# ArangoDB init container fails on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, arangodb, minikube

I'm working on a NodeJS service which uses ArangoDB as datastore, and deployed on minikube. I use an initContainer directive in the kubernetes deployment manifest to ensure that the database is ready to receive connections before the application attempts to connect. The relevant portion of the kubernetes YAML is shown below:

```yaml
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: carservice
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-carservice
          image: arangodb/arangodb:3.5.1
          command: ['sh', 'c', 'arangosh --server.endpoint="https://${CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_HOST}:${CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_PORT}" --server.password=""; do echo waiting for database to be up; sleep 2; done;']
      containers:
        - name: carservice
          image: carservice
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

The challenge has been that sometimes the initContainer is able to wait for the database connection to be established successfully. Most of the other times, it randomly fails with the error:

**ERROR caught exception: invalid endpoint spec: https://**

Out of desperation, I changed the scheme to http, and it fails with a corresponding error:

**ERROR caught exception: invalid endpoint spec: http://**

My understanding of these errors is that the database is not able to recognize https and http in these instances, which is strange. The few times the initContainer bit worked successfully, I used https in the related command in the kubernetes spec.

I must add that the actual database (***https://${CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_HOST}:${CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_PORT}***) has been successfully deployed to minikube using kube-arangodb, and can be accessed through the web UI, so that bit is sorted.

What I'd like to know:

1. Is this the recommended way to wait for ArangoDB to connect using the initContainer directive, or do I have to use an entirely different approach?
2. What could be causing the error I'm getting? Am I missing something fundamental here?

Would be glad for any help.

Comment: Seems not able to read variable CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_HOST and CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_PORT thus your URL becomes only http://   . look at env variables

Comment: You're right @ankidaemon. For the cases where the init container starts successfully, the env variables are set correctly.  What I don't get is why this happens. What would cause env variables to not be set? The ArangoDB pod correctly has the env variables set. I think the internal DNS provided by kubernetes would be handy here. My only concern is that when it's finally substituted in the shell command of the initContainer directive, it'd appear as a string and not the corresponding IP. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that for those times the init container failed to connect to ArangoDB, the env variables were not correctly set. Therefore, I added another init container before that (since init containers are executed in sequence),  that'd wait for the corresponding kubernetes "service" resource of the ArangoDB deployment to come up. That way, by the time the second init container would run, the env variables would be available.

The corresponding portion of kubernetes deployment YAML is shown as:

```yaml
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: carservice
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name:init-db-service
          image: busybox:1.28
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup carservice-carservicedb; do echo waiting for kubernetes service resource for db; sleep 2; done;']

        - name: init-carservice
          image: arangodb/arangodb:3.5.1
          command: ['sh', 'c', 'arangosh --server.endpoint="https://${CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_HOST}:${CARSERVICE_CARSERVICEDB_SERVICE_PORT}" --server.password=""; do echo waiting for database to be up; sleep 2; done;']
      containers:
        - name: carservice
          image: carservice
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```